# Similar values in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that stores some values. I'm trying to detect the similar values and add them to new array.

example:

```
  $arrayA = array( 1,4,5,6,4,2,1);

  $newarray = (4,1);
```

Any help?

Comment: By "similar" do you mean "duplicated"?

Comment: what are you saying EXACTLY ???

Comment: i'm trying to create two arrays from one. In array A i want  
separate duplicated values and insert them into array B and array A includes only single values

Answer (score 1):

Use the array_intersect() method. For example

```
$arrayA = array(1,4,5,6,4,2,1);
$arrayB = array(4,1);

$common_values = array_intersect($arrayA, $arrayB);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$array = array(1,4,5,6,4,2,1);
$duplicates = array_unique(array_diff_assoc($array, array_unique($array)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1 = array( 1,4,5,6,4,2,1);
$a = array();
foreach($a1 as $value){
  if(!in_array($value, $a)){
    $a[] = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayA = array(1,4,5,6,4,2,1);
$newarray = array_diff_assoc($arrayA, array_unique($arrayA));
```